# YQL finance data with Java script not returning all queries each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, yahoo-finance

I am trying to incorporate financial data in my website (just a beginner)
I followed a youtube documentary that used some java script to to the query from a local machine not a server.

the script was supposed to return price daily changes to 4 different shares and display them.

It seemed to work at first, but now i see that it only returns some of the prices (or occasionally none) and when I refresh it may show a different change but never all 4 at the same time?

here is the HTML and Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var Base_URL = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=';
var yql_query = 'select * from yahoo.finance.quote where symbol in ("YHOO","AAPL","GOOG","MSFT")';
var yql_query_str = encodeURI(Base_URL+yql_query);
var query_str_final = yql_query_str + '&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys';

$.getJSON(query_str_final, function(data){ console.log(data);
var changeValue = data.query.results.quote[0].Change;
console.log(changeValue);
document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = " Yahoo = " + changeValue; });

$.getJSON(query_str_final, function(data){ console.log(data);
var changeValue = data.query.results.quote[1].Change;
console.log(changeValue);
document.getElementById("change1").innerHTML = " Apple = " + changeValue; });

$.getJSON(query_str_final, function(data){ console.log(data);
var changeValue = data.query.results.quote[2].Change;
console.log(changeValue);
document.getElementById("change2").innerHTML = " Google = " + changeValue; });

$.getJSON(query_str_final, function(data){ console.log(data);
var changeValue = data.query.results.quote[3].Change;
console.log(changeValue);
document.getElementById("change3").innerHTML = " Microsoft = " + changeValue; });

</script>
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Are all the console.logs showing the correct data being returned?

Comment: i think so just not all at the same time. Except Yahoo which ha changed its name

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this where the `changeValue` ie `1,2,3 etc` for each has a slightly different variable name plus the html change is done when the process is complete.

```
$.getJSON(query_str_final, function(data){ console.log(data);
changeValue1 = data.query.results.quote[1].Change;
console.log(changeValue);
}).done(function(){
    document.getElementById("change1").innerHTML = " Apple = " + 
changeValue1;});
```

Note: This makes the changValue1 variable global,  which isn't the best but for testing.